# Master Equation for Population Growth

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The growth of a population $Q$ is described by the following evolution equations:

$$
\boxed{
\begin{array}{cccc}
     (\textrm{i}) \hspace{0,3cm} \textrm{Q} \xrightarrow[]{\sigma} \textrm{Q} +\textrm{Q} \\
     \\
     (\textrm{ii}) \hspace{0,3cm} \textrm{Q} \xrightarrow[]{\mu} 0\\
     \\
      (\textrm{iii}) \hspace{0,3cm} \textrm{Q} + \textrm{Q} \xrightarrow[]{\lambda} \textrm{Q} \\
\end{array}
}
$$ \

where $\mu$ , $\sigma$ and $\lambda$ are the rates at which those occur. For a population with $n$ elements, the transion rates are:

$$ \omega_{n,n+1}= \sigma n , \hspace{0,5cm} \omega_{n,n-1} = n ( \mu + \lambda)$$

so, the master equation will look like:

$$ \frac{\partial P}{\partial t} = P(n+1,t) [(n+1)(\mu + \lambda)] + P(n-1,t) \sigma(n-1) - P(n,t) n \{ \sigma  + \mu + \lambda \}   \hspace{1 cm}(1) $$

Now I make use of the generating function:

$$ F(z) = \sum_{n= - \infty}^{\infty} z^n P(n,t)$$

and write (1) as a dynamical equation for $\left\langle n \right\rangle$, by multiplying ($1$) by $\sum_n z^n$ and noticing that:

$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}  = \sum_nnz^{n-1} P(n,t) \longrightarrow  \left(  \frac{\partial F}{\partial z} \right) \Big|_{z=1} = \left\langle n \right\rangle $$

$$ \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial z^2} = \sum_n(n-1)nz^{n-2} P(n,t) \longrightarrow   \left(  \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial z^2} \right) \Big|_{z=1} = \left\langle n^2 \right\rangle -\left\langle n \right\rangle  $$

I arrived at:

$$ \frac{\partial \left\langle n \right\rangle}{\partial t} = \left\langle n \right\rangle \left( - \lambda - \mu + \sigma \right)$$

This equation is supposed to have terms with $\left\langle n^2 \right\rangle$ but I dont know what I did wrong here. Any help?

Comment: Perhaps you can elaborate on how you after “arriving at:” the final expression.

Comment: @AlexR. I edited the question, hopefully thats enough